# Return from calling function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two function like below:

```
var doSomething = function() {
    // first check if user wants to proceed and some other restrictions
    checkIfReallyShouldProceed();
    console.log('ok, proceed');
    // proceed and do something
}

var checkIfReallyShouldProceed = function() {
    var check = confirm('really proceed?');
    if(!check){
    //stop executing doSomething
    }
}

doSomething();
```

If the user does not confirm I want to return from doSomething. Of course I could return the result of the check variable to doSomething and have something like

```
if(!checkIfReallyShouldProceed()){
  return;
}
```

there, but I want the called function to stop the calling function from executing. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: What you've outlined yourself as a solution is a good way to go, given you add the necessary `()` to it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. Beside the fact, that the if condition would work, I would like to know if it is possible to return from the calling function. Consider it to be a theoretical question :-)

Comment: You could throw an exception from checkIfReallyShouldProceed and catch it in doSomething.

Answer (score -1):

An `if` condition is made for this type of conditional procedure:

```
var doSomething = function() {
    if (checkIfReallyShouldProceed()){
      return true; // This will stop the doSomething function from executing
    }

    console.log('ok, proceed');
}

var checkIfReallyShouldProceed = function() {
    return confirm('really proceed?'); // returns true/false
}

doSomething();
```

In the `checkIfReallyShouldProceed` function, return whether or not the user wants to proceed. In `doSomething`, it will stop executing if the called method returns `true`